# I/O and RAM limitations are important for Hadoop performance. But is disk speed related to I/O?

Tags: performance, memory, io, hadoop

[Hortonworks says this](http://hortonworks.com/kb/linux-file-systems-for-hdfs/): "Most often performance of a Hadoop cluster will not be constrained by disk speed – I/O and RAM limitations will be more important."  *

How is disk speed not related to I/O limitations?

Answer (score 2):

The comment is technically correct, but it's nuanced.  You have to understand what your MapReduce jobs are doing.

While disk rotational speed is important, it's arguably less important than *network* speed, both off system and off switch, especially in the case where you generate large amounts of input data into your reduce phase, since reducers cannot take into account data locality.

More often than not, you're going to find clusters that utilize 7200rpm drives, configured in [JBOD](http://www.ghostar.org/2014/10/hadoop-cluster-data-needs-no-raid/) (because that's the general recommendation by the Hadoop community to balance cost vs performance vs reliability). In most configurations, you're *probably* not going to find more than 1-2 readers/writers going to each spindle (think:  1-2 tasks per spindle).  The performance isn't going to be improved much due to improving the rotational latency (though, I'm deliberately sidestepping the issue of SSD here).

With modern 7200rpm drives, you're going to get between 100-200MBytes/s ... or the equivalent of 1-2Gbps a second.  My clusters are built to do about about 25Gbps of *disk* I/O ... but in order to utilize that performance during the shuffle and reduce phase, I need to have  *at least* that much performance available at the network just to get the data off the system.

That just gets me (almost) 1:1 oversubscription if I only have to communicate to other nodes on-switch.  If my cluster bridges multiple switches, I now have to make sure I have sufficient capacity to handle the significant amounts of east-west traffic that can occur during the shuffle, as data is moved from the mappers into the reducers.

All the disk i/o in the world isn't helpful if you can't get the data where it's needed in the cluster.  Data locality and rack awareness help, but only during certain portions of the whole MR process.

Answer (score 1):

> How is disk speed not related to I/O limitations?

I'm totally with you on this, they are linked, especially for Hadoop - I've just finished designing a new pair of clusters and disk speed was definitely an important aspect of that.

Comment: +1. The statement, as it stands, makes no logical sense at all. Maybe there is some angle that is badly explained - but that is the author's problem. I would suggest the OP to contact the author and ask for a clarification / edit of that part.

Answer (score 0):

Possible interpretations:

- not all I/O is disk I/O, network I/O is often an issue in clustered
  environments
- the number and configurations of disks have often higher impact on
  the overall disk I/O than the speed of the disk itself (for example 2
  slower disks in a RAID0 config can outperform a single very fast disk
  at the same overall price)
- RAM limitations will always beat disk speed - as soon as the system
  starts swapping the performance will drop no matter how fast your
  disk is (true, not directly related to I/O)